# Bootstrap progress bar height not matching with others

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with a uploader and I am using bootstrap progress bar with custom height.

After use several progress bar, after four o five of them at the same time in the same div, some progress not show the same height like the others.

This is the jsbin to see that behavior:

[Github gist with jsbin link on comment](https://gist.github.com/LTroya/b7b668ffc0a1f21b0e1faacd11a5aa6b)

**------ UPDATE -------**

[image: This is how I see it]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: seems fine to me.

Comment: I add a screenshot about how I see the progressbars. Didn't you see like that?

Comment: Same problem for me, somone can help ?